# Can't extend /home partition with the space on the right

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, gparted

I have booted on a live Ubuntu Usb and I wanted to extend  my /home directory partition because I need more space. I have allocated free space right next to the home directory but I cant Extend the partition.

As you can see i have allocated free space to the right of the home directory:

[image: As you can see i have allocated free space to the right of the home directory]

But when I want to extend the home directory partition, it's not possible. There is no space to extend:

[image: There is no space to extend]

I don't know if this problem have something to do with logical and physical partition but I needed to extend the home partition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Step 0: Backup your data

Make sure you have up to date and good backup of all your personal files. The backup must be outside your computer. If you haven't backed up your data, **stop now** and make backup.

#### Step 1: Boot from an Ubuntu Live Installation CD/DVD/USB

This is important, as you can't change a tire of a car while you are driving it.

Select the **Try Ubuntu** option.

#### Step 2: Disable Swap

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, or click on the Terminal icon of live CD desktop

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

#### Step 3: Resize Extended Partition `/dev/sda4`

The logical partition can't be resized until the extended partition in which it resides has the extra space. After the `/dev/sda4` is increased to take up all the unallocated space to its right, then there will be space to increase `/dev/sda7`.

#### Step 4: Apply

Press the Apply button to actually do the step above. If there is an error, **stop**.

#### Step 5: Resize Logical Partition `/dev/sda7`

Now you should be able to resize the `/dev/sda7`.

#### Step 6: Apply

Press the Apply button to actually do the step above. If there is an error, **stop**.

Hope this helps

Comment: you forgot to mention that in order to resize or move partition you have to swapoff the swap partition. This will unlock /dev/sda4

Comment: @crispy Thanks! I didn't think you would need to disable swap, but as you had to do that, I have added that step in my answer now.