# Problem resizing partitions in the middle of the drive with GParted on dual-boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have a dual-boot PC with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. I recently ran out of space, and I had to replace my HDD with a bigger one, copying everything from the old to the new. Ubuntu still is running low on space and that's because the partitions have still the same size. I tried using GParted from a live USB, but it doesn't let me give Ubuntu more space. I tried a variety of solutions but none of them worked. My other Partitions are:

1. Windows
2. System
3. Linux (made of 2 smaller partitons)
4. Recovery.

[image: Partitions on my HDD]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: You cannot resize a mounted partition - a key icon is shown in gparted if the partition is mounted. You must reboot into a live session and use gparted there.

Comment: @OrganicMarble For some reason I can still shrink the partition of Ubuntu but not to give it more space. I also use a live USB witch solves this problem.

Comment: @user535733 That is what I was trying to achive _before_ writing this post.

Comment: I’d guess your unallocated space is at the end of the drive and it sounds like the recovery partition is between that and the Linux partitions. If that is the case you need to move the recovery partition to the end of the drive (do that in Windows) and then you should be able to adjust the size of the Linux partitions. Add a screenshot of GParted showing the disk if you are still stuck.

Comment: Use **Windows Disk Management** if you want to resize a partition with Windows on it. Even the GParted site recommends this.

Comment: @PonJar Yes, that is the case! How can I move the Recovery partition at the end?

Comment: Go into Windows. Right click the start button. You should see Windows disk management . Click it. That should launch it. Select the recovery partition. It should be self evident how to move it. Move it all the way to the right, probably best not to resize it. Once that is done you can use GParted in a live environment to make changes to the Linux partitions. You will have to resize sda4 first to take up all the available space. That should move the unallocated space inside sda4. Then resize sda6. Don’t touch sda5.

Comment: Well, I couldn't do anything with **Disk Management** and I used a tool called _AOMEI_. I moved the _Recovery Partition_ at the end of the disk but for some reason it created a small partition of unallocated space (250MB) and when I tried using GParted from the bootable USB and nothing changed. Do you have any other ideas? (Btw, sorry for the late reply)

Comment: Sounds like you did not click Apply Changes when you were using GParted

Comment: @PonJar When I tried to resize my partiton I had the same problem as before. I could only shrink the partition. (_Note: If you want I can include a screenshot_)

Comment: A screenshot might help. From what you have said I’d expect to see unallocated space between sda4 and sda3. What you have to do is expand sda4 first. Make sure you click apply. Then you should be able to expand sda6. If this isn’t working we do need to see a new screenshot of the current partition layout to see what’s stopping it. One final thing, you have to be in a live environment to do this so boot the Ubuntu installer, choose try Ubuntu and run GParted from the live environment desktop

Comment: @PonJar I can't believe I am such an idiot!! I was trying to resize only one part of the main partition, (the /Home part. only) and when I was going to take a screenshot I realized I could give it more space! Thank you sooo much! :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't extend /home partition with the space on the right](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312282/cant-extend-home-partition-with-the-space-on-the-right)

Comment: I 've solved the problem already, but thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I move the Recovery Partition at the end if the disk using a tool called *AOMEI*.
Then I tried to resize the main partition of Ubuntu (my files and the system files), and it created some space inside the main partition. I resized the partition containig my files and it worked!