# Resize linux virtual partition

Tags: filesystem, resize, parted

Considering the following scenario...

```
NAME MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
vda  252:0    0  200G  0 disk
vda1 252:1    0  512M  0 part /boot/efi
vda2 252:2    0    1K  0 part
vda5 252:5    0 49,5G  0 part /

Disk /dev/vda: 200 GiB, 214748364800 bytes, 419430400 sectors

Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0c0f76c8

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/vda1  *       2048   1050623   1048576  512M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/vda2       1052670 104855551 103802882 49,5G  5 Extended
/dev/vda5       1052672 104855551 103802880 49,5G 83 Linux
```

how to resize /dev/vda5 to extend up to all the 200GB space of /dev/vda?
What should be done concerning /dev/sda2 holding the extended partion inside which is the logical partition vda5?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: ubuntu 20.04 LTS focal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Also see [Can't extend /home partition with the space on the right](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312282/cant-extend-home-partition-with-the-space-on-the-right).

Comment: Thanks, i did it by first resing the extended and the logical partitions (parted->resizepart first 2 and then 5) up to 200Gb and then resizing the filesystem on the logical partition (resize2fs /dev/vda5)